Why can't I use comment environment with xsim?
I am writing some lecture notes in which I want to add some hints for exercises.
To do that I use the package xsim and I create a new environment for hint.
And sometimes I also need to call some functions that are commenting some lines.
But when I use an comment environment within my hint environment, I get an error message: Argument of \xComment has an extra }. <inserted text> \par l.57 \end{hint} Runaway argument?
I got the same issue, using the by default exercise environment, but with no usable error message. (So I don't think that the problem comes from my environment definition).
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass{article} 

    \usepackage{comment}
    \usepackage{xsim}
        \DeclareExerciseProperty{hint}
        
        \ExplSyntaxOn
            \bool_new:N \l_xsim_hint_bool
            
            \keys_define:nn {xsim}
            { hint/print .bool_set:N = \l_xsim_hint_bool }
            
            
            \NewDocumentEnvironment{hint}{+b}
            {%
                \tl_set:NV \ExerciseType \g_xsim_exercise_type_tl
                \tl_set:NV \ExerciseID \g_xsim_exercise_id_tl
                \SetExerciseProperty {hint} {#1}
                \bool_if:NT \l_xsim_hint_bool
                {
                    \par\medskip
                    \underline{\itshape Hint \nobreakspace \GetExerciseProperty{counter}}\,:\nobreakspace 
                    {#1}
                }
            }
            {}
        \ExplSyntaxOff
                
        %% description list for hints
        \newcommand\printhints{%
            \begin{description}
                \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{%
                    \GetExercisePropertyT{hint}
                    {\item[Hint ##3]####1}%
                }%
            \end{description}
        }
        
        %% Declare to print hint
        \xsimsetup{
            hint/print = true 
        }


\begin{document} 

    \begin{comment}
        no problem
    \end{comment}

    \begin{hint}
        Let us remark that $a+b=0$.
        
        \begin{comment}
            problem
        \end{comment}
    \end{hint}

    % \begin{exercise}
    %   Let us remark that $a+b=0$.
        
    %   \begin{comment}
    %       problem
    %   \end{comment}
    % \end{exercise}

\end{document}
%EoF

How could I solve this problem ?

you can not use verbatim or comment environments in the argument of another command, and an environment with b is really a command with argument as shown by #1

@DavidCarlisle Is there a way to work around ? I though LaTeX3 was able to solve this kind of situation. Or is it possible to hide (not print) things that are within an environment using another (and compatible) solution ? Or is it an unsolvable problem ?

you can't use catcode changes as they have no effect. You could use other ways of hiding things eg \iffalse hide this \fi but note you could not hide a mis-matched { that way as you could in a real comment as the braces are read before the \iffalse is seen, L3 is written in TeX it provides some useful functions but it does not change the fundamental  processing model of the language.

So if understand well a solution is to create a new environment for comments where the body is not printed.

that would work there is no problem  having any nested enviornment that hides normal code, but comment and verbatim enviornments disable the meaning of { and % etc so you can comment out mis-matched braces so a single open { for example, and you can not do that here as such a mis-matched brace will already have broken the outer argument body parsing.

I understand, no magical solution here. In my use-case (for now), it seems to be enough. You can turn you comments into an answer :)  If you want to add an example (and maybe a counter-example) it would be perfect.
